# Shell-- print only certain lines from output

Tags: bash, shell

I need to choose from output only lines where number is bigger than chosen number.

For example `x=27` and I need to find only lines where the number in first column is bigger than that x. In this case: only third and fourth line and first and second would be thrown away.

```
25 text
26 text
30 text
35 text
```

Output would look like this:

```
30 text
35 text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pipe output via following script

```
| while read a b ; do [ $a -gt 27 ] && echo "$a $b" ; done
```

or

```
| while read ; do [ ${REPLY% *} -gt 27 ] && echo "$REPLY" ; done
```

but easyest through `awk`

```
| awk '$1 > 27'
```